# Need reference for seemingly trivial statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, order-theory

For any countable family of sets $\mathfrak{F}$ there is totally ordered (by inclusion) family of sets $\mathfrak{T}$, for which $\sigma(\mathfrak{F}) = \sigma(\mathfrak{T})$.

$\sigma(\ldots)$ here means "$\sigma$-algebra, generated by ..."

Comment: Might be helpful to explain what $\sigma$ is.

Comment: @Klaus, done, sorry.